# Name for PCB isolating tape (usually found in notebooks)

Tags: pcb, protection, isolation

Looking for the name and, at best, part number for the tape usually used to isolate the PCBs, in particular inside notebooks (black tape on the pic below):

[image]

My design is having through-hole capacitors lying on the board, and while they are in the protective insulating sleeve and board is having mask under it, I want to consider putting additional protection between them.

Bigger picture:

[image]

I do not have naked NB MB right now to shot, and funny enough it appears uneasy finding good quality picture (without alibaba seller name on it)!

This tape is usually used between CD-ROM assembly and PCB (as protection against physical damage to PCB when CD-ROM is removed and inserted), between boards to ensure no accidental contact between board assemblies, and between other mechanical components (e.g. cooler) and PCB. The tape (film) is having glue at one side. I am sure people familiar with notebook design / repair must know what the tape / film is.

Comment: probably unobtanium tape. got a bigger photo resolution of the texture than a thumbnail of the whole assembly?

Comment: Black polyimide tape ? (basically black Kapton tape)

Comment: Voting to close this question as most correct answers will be unacceptable within quality standards, i.e., a single-line response such as "adhesive-backed polyester film".

Answer (score 1):

The black stuff is probably "acetate cloth electrical tape". 3M makes a number of different types, and they're all available in various widths (some subject to MOQ, of course- they will typically split a full width to order and you'll get however many rolls that amounts to- something like 36" = 915mm).

There are also conductive tapes that generally have a silvery appearance that are used for EMI shielding.

Comment: I'm not so sure. I've repaired plenty of laptops and the tape I've seen is always smooth, shiny, clearly some kind of plastic. All the "acetate cloth electrical tape" I can find clearly has the texture of... well cloth.

Comment: @Unimportant Yes, I’ve seen both. Should be obvious if it’s fabric texture.